# Hey look, we have reduced our [weight]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Ref: [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight)

It's a patchwork quilt of unrelated items (I came across it when working on an `igraph` R question). No wiki. No explanation as to what it should be applied to.

I'd vote to make it graph-specific or nix it.

Comment: There is certainly reason to change [tag:android] + [tag:weight] -> [tag:android-layout-weight] (see similar tags [tag:android-layout], [tag:android-linearlayout]. I spot a few [tag:fonts]+[tag:weight], where 'font weight' *is* a valid term. Suggestion for that: [tag:font-weight] (and burn [tag:bold] plz; off hand I cannot see a single question re: its description)

Comment: @Jongware You should probably post that as an answer

Comment: Aww. [tag:weight] is a *mess*. I stopped checking questions when it got intermixed with [tag:bold]. I'm going to leave this one for edit-rep hunters.

Comment: Burn it with fire! :P

Comment: @Jongware the problem is that most of the rep-hunters will only touch the tag; and get rejected unless they end up matched with robo reviewers...

Comment: Is there a way to see how many times `[weight]` has been searched for by folks?

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +47/-2. A1 (Saying -): +4/0

Comment: I think we've [weight]ed long enough to burninate this tag, which is ambiguous at best.

Comment: Burn the wights! I mean [weight]s!

Comment: There is also a tag [tag:weighted] (316 questions): *The weighted tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?*  This seems even worse than [tag:weight].  Should we burn the more-common [tag:weight] while leaving around [tag:weighted]?  Or can we provide guidance for [tag:weighted] and move some of the [tag:weight] questions there?

Comment: And also [tag:weighting].

Comment: New title: Can we burn this extra [weight]?

Comment: @Vality: can't we burn with ice for once?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +105/-9. A1: +35/-1. A2 (Saying Yes): +32/-1. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: @dbc feel free to post a new burn request for each of those two. [weighting] is a <50 post burn, so it will not need the full burnination, and can be done quickly.

Comment: @BhargavRao - I think there might be a call for a [tag:weighted] or [tag:weighting] tag, given that it seems to be a well-defined concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting: *The process of weighting involves emphasizing the contribution of particular aspects of a phenomenon (or of a set of data) over others to a final outcome or result; thereby highlighting those aspects in comparison to others in the analysis.*  The tag seems widely used by the [tag:r] community; with proper guidance I think one of the two could survive.  (This is outside my area of expertise though.)

Comment: Cool, I'll look for some experts in the [r] tag and ask them.

Answer (score 33):

Since there seems to be consensus and not a good reason for not doing it, let's list the problematic combinations as noted by [Jongware](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269165#comment81324_269165):

- Replace all [[android] + [layout] + [weight]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+weight+layout) for [android-layout-weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout-weight) x ~140
- Fix tags of most of [[fonts] + [weight]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fonts+weight) x 12

There isn't any other combination that seems problematic. There are many questions that lacks the proper tags (ie. obvious css questions without the css tag), but most of them don't require more than that:

- 6 questions [are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[weight]%20closed%3A1), some without answers. If they can be reopened, reopen, otherwise delete.
- 11 questions [have negative score](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[weight]%20is%3Aq%20score%3A..-1). If there's something that can be fixed, fix it, if it needs to be closed, vote to close.

Comment: Is this answer saying burn it, or just clean it up?

Comment: @DanNeely what is the definition of burn it? Right now I don't know. The only thing I know is that the actions described in the answer would be better than the current status.

Comment: burning would be to remove the tag entirely after retaging any questions that have good replacements like android-layout-weight, and closing/deleting any bad questions.  A cleanup would fix problematic questions, but leave the tag in place.

Comment: @DanNeely then I'm not saying to burn or not to burn. If the tag ends up deleted after the retag and cleanup process, that's just the natural result of doing small good things.

Comment: So this is a very good partial answer (+1 from me) but it doesn't actually say burn or clean up which means it doesn't actually answer the question, and we need to look at another answer to decide. Right now, the only other answer says burn.

Comment: @Joshua An answer on a Meta [tag:discussion] does not need to provide a definitive answer. It need only meaningfully contribute to the discussion.

Comment: @Joshua when I answered this question, it was asking what to do with the tag. I suggested a solution.

Comment: Yay for the ˜5 year backlog :)

Comment: @Luuklag the backlog is even longer than that.  There're unresolved burn/retag requests going back to 2012.  The current estimate is 9 years to clear the backlog.  https://rodgort.sobotics.org/requests?query=&searchBy=&trackingStatusId=-1&status=none&requestType=&pageNumber=87&hasQuestions=yes&sortBy=age

Comment: @DanNeely, I know there are older ones, but just pointing out that this answer was written almost 5 years ago. And to be honest, should we really take action on all those requests. I doubt it!

Comment: @Luuklag what are you proposing? That because the problem is old, it's not worth the effort to solve it? Or that there is no problem to begin with?

Comment: @Braiam neither. If there is a problem the burn request will be (highly) upvoted, and probably has many dupes closed against it. If its (not) worth the effort solely depends on the tag under consideration, nothing to do with the age of the request. Looking at the oldest request with only a limited number of upvotes (<30) the priority isn't very high there so no need to action on them now, and maybe ever.

Comment: @Luuklag you seem to think people actually find moderating tasks at all necessary. Heck, some people would do away with downvoting/close voting if given the opportunity. Managing tags is a moderating tag, since the content itself is reorganized. Moderating tasks aren't easy to do either.

Comment: task* darn it. I've typed tag a little too many times.

Comment: Heh, I hear you. I declined an incorrect "question merge" request with a custom reason where I mistyped "question merge" as "tag merge".

Answer (score 33):

Burn it.

- It's used [on a question about creating a constrained user input GUI, which is not really about weights in the mathematical sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7867755/1394393). [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) doesn't add any useful information here.
- It's used on [this question about converting a multigraph to a weighted graph](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12998456/1394393). [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) doesn't add any meaningful information here. [weighted-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighted-graph) would be far better.
- It's used [to refer to physical weight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5747444/1394393), in spite of the tag description.
- It's used [with regard scaling symbol size on a graph with respect to number of data points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12624771/1394393).
- It's used to refer to [weighting a random selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1398113/1394393).
- It's [still used for fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40757482/1394393).
- There are many, many questions regarding Android layouts, as described elsewhere in this question.

Most of these are from about half of the first page of questions.

As you can see, it's used for an extremely broad range of topics, not even limited to the already broad statistical meaning of "weight," per the tag description. This tag adds nothing to the questions, and it's taking the place of better tags in many cases.

As such, it fails all the (incredibly vague and confusing) burination criteria:

1. It does not describe the contents of the question to which it is applied. It's supposed to refer roughly to the statistical meaning, but since it's used for other meanings in many cases, you can't know what the term's relevance to the question is until you read it. Even other tags aren't typically clarifying.
2. The topic of statistical weights is not on topic. This is because it's not really a topic that's specifically studied by experts (meaning there can't be questions specifically about the topic) and because raw stats or graph questions wouldn't be on topic anyway. It is sometimes tangentially related, but those situations are better covered by *topical* tags related to graph concepts, font concepts, or other topics more directly related to programming.
3. The tag adds no meaningful information. More meaningful information would be added by better tags like those mentioned in the previous point.
4. It does not mean the same thing in all common contexts. Its misuse demonstrates that.

Comment: There is also a tag [tag:weighted] (316 questions): *The weighted tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?*  This seems even worse than [tag:weight].  Should we burn the more-common [tag:weight] while leaving around [tag:weighted]?  Or can we provide guidance for [tag:weighted] and move some of the [tag:weight] questions there?

Comment: If I [search for all tags containing *weight*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*weight*) I see the following tags: *Tagged with weight or  weighted or  android-layout-weight or  weighted-average or  flyweight-pattern or  weighted-graph or  weighting or  hammingweight or  lightweight-processes or  boost-flyweight or  uifontweighttrait or  weighttp or  lightweight-stream-api*  [tag:weighted] and [tag:weighting] also seem problematic.

Comment: @dbc I debated mentioning the similar tags. You should post an answer about it.

Answer (score 9):

[weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Use [android-layout-weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout-weight) for questions related to assigning a layout weight to LinearLayout in Android.
- Use [weighted-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighted-graph) for questions related to weighted graphs.
- Use [weighted-average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weighted-average) for questions related to weighted average.

## Progress:

The [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=weight),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweight%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweight%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweight%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweight%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193489)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=269165)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weight) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.